# Future get returns null from executor service submit

Tags: groovy

While performing an initial phase of Java to Groovy code migration I encountered a problem where the Groovy version returns null from the Future while Java returns the correct integer (123).

The only changes made between J1.java and G1.groovy are the class name and lambda to closure conversion.

//file: J1.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
public class J1 {
  public static void main (String... args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (1);
    Future<Integer> future = executor.submit (() -> 123);
    System.out.println ("Result: " + future.get ());
    executor.shutdown ();
  }
}
```

//file: G1.groovy

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
public class G1 {
  public static void main (String... args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (1);
    Future<Integer> future = executor.submit ({ -> 123 });
    System.out.println ("Result: " + future.get ());
    executor.shutdown ();
  }
}
```

> Java Result: 123
>
> Groovy result: null

Is this expected and if so why?  I have tried numerous variations all producing the same result.  Is there something that I am missing to produce the same result using Groovy?

```
Groovy: 2.4.5
Java: 1.8 64-bit
Platform: Windows 7 64-bit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Groovy, a closure is a `Runnable` and a `Callable`.

Unfortunaly, when you call `executor.submit { .. }`, the runtime choose to call `executor.submit(Runnable)` which doesn't return a value.

You should explicitly cast your closure to a Callable :

```
def executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
def future = executor.submit ({ -> 123 } as Callable)
println "Result: ${future.get()}"
executor.shutdown()
```